# String substitution with file contents

Tags: string, bash

I have a file called `tags.txt` which contains a tag on each line, for example:

```
workflow
blogging
writing
```

Using the ["Advanced Bash Scripting Guide"](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) I've written a Bash script that takes these lines and makes them into a single-line comma-delimited list.

```
tagsraw=$(<tags.txt)
tags=${tagsraw//$'\n'/', '}
```

How can I do this in one line of code?

Whenever I have tried putting the `(<tags.txt)` in place of `tagsraw` in the second line, in numerous forms, I get a "bad substitution" error. Is doing this on one line, without an intermediary variable, in Bash even possible?

Comment: Using bash, you can't avoid using `tagsraw`. Obviously you can put both lines in one with a `;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk`:

```
tags="$(awk -v OFS=', ' -v RS= '{$1=$1}1' tags.txt)"
echo "$tags"
workflow, blogging, writing
```

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted this as it seems to work for me. I will look up how to break down the command, see how those options work, before accepting the answer.